# Start Android simulator failure with Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Here is my situation:

My simulator parameter:

[image: Hardware]

My system image selection:

[image: System Image]

My Configuration is:

[image: configuration]

I tried all three options but no one can help me run the simulator.

When I run the simulator first it shows me an error:

[image: error]

And the Android Studio gives me the error:

```
14:42   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\CZD\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_24.avd/userdata.img

14:42   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

14:42   Emulator: qemu-system-armel.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
```

It is strange that when I start the simulator for second time. Android Studio only gives me too errors:

```
14:45   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

14:45   Emulator: qemu-system-armel.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
```

I tried everything to solve this problem, but I failed.

Comment: start emulator as **Cold Boot Now** and check

Comment: @VladSpirin: please do not amend image Markdown to code format. These would have best been amended by adding a `!` at the start, so they appear inline. I have made that change now.

Comment: @Jaymin I tried your method, but it didn't work.

Comment: @halfer Thanks. I tried it before but the website told me I have no privilege to do this.

Comment: @JasonCai: no worries, that's normal for new users. An editor with more experience did try to do that, but didn't quite format it correctly. All sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Android Studio in Windows.

1) Don't use armeabi image. As recommendation, you should consider x86 image.
[image: x86 Images]

2) For first start the Emulator will take time to boost up, so it's normal seeing this black screen.
Therefore, once you change to x86 images, it will work well

Comment: You're right. I do use Android Studio on Windows. I'm trying to run projects from other guys. The project didn't support x86 abi. So, I wanna to run it first which get this error.

Comment: @JasonCai in this case, using a real phone instead, should be helpful

Comment: That could be one solution.  Any other?